# render multiple objects to a users profile page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, render

I am trying to show the 'status' & 'project' from an '@user' on that users profile page, I believe I have the correct relationships etc but the error I am getting is that I cannot call render multiple times in one action.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
def show
@user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])
if @user 
    @statuses = @user.statuses.all
    render actions: :show
else 
    render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
end

@user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])
if @user 
    @projects = @user.projects.all
    render actions: :show
else 
    render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
end
end

end
```

What is the best way to express the above, to render both items on the users profile page without calling render twice?

This is my view:

```
  <div class="container">
<div class="page-header">
<h1><%= "Hi " + @user.first_name + "!" %>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= link_to "Create Project", new_project_path, class: "btn btn-success btn-block" %>
</div>

<% if @statuses %>
    <% @statuses.each do |status| %>
    <div class="well">
        <%= status.content %>
        <hr />
        <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(status.created_at), status_path(status) %> ago
    </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if @projects %>
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <div class="well">
        <%= project.title %>
        <hr />
        <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(project.created_at), projects_path(project) %> ago
    </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
    </div>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: update question with relevant view code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as below.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
 def show
   @user = User.find_by_profile_name(params[:id])
    if @user 
      @statuses = @user.statuses.all
      @projects = @user.projects.all
      render action: :show
    else 
      render file: 'public/404', status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end  
  end
end
```

Comment: This makes sense to look at but gives a "statement invalid error" to do with sqlite3. I have updated my views in the question.

Comment: Not sure on which line your are getting 'statement invalid error'.. can u try to render view of show action. example: (render 'posts/show' or render :template => 'posts/show') instead of render actions: :show

Comment: i think there is typo mistake in (render actions: :show).. it should be plural (action) example- format.html { render action: 'show' }

Comment: Thanks so much @Dave your solution got me past the error I was getting so that I could realise I had an issue in my DB file. Working perfectly now cheers!